# Passing a pair of String and Integer to the onProgressUpdate() via publishProgress() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here's the scenario.

I've two progress elements : 1)  `ProgressBar`(Progress)  And 2) `TextView`(Status).

As of now, for passing the status  and progress together, I have created an AsyncTask by extending it like `extends AsyncTask<String,JSONObject, String>`. It is working as well.

However, Is there an efficient way to pass the  `String` and  `Integer` to the `onProgressUpdate()` than parsing them as JSON ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [`Pair`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) class.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about that. :-) . Thanks.